# npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')

Tags: npm, npm-install, hexo

After I installed hexo, I used npm install to complete the packages in package.json, but he reported an error, the content of the error is as follows
❯ node --version
v18.12.1
❯ npm --version
9.1.3

```
❯ npm install

············

npm WARN   dev eslint-config-standard@"12.0.0" from compression@1.7.4
npm WARN   node_modules/.pnpm/compression@1.7.4/node_modules/compression
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: babel-eslint@11.0.0-beta.2
npm WARN Found: eslint@5.16.0
npm WARN node_modules/.pnpm/cross-spawn@7.0.3/node_modules/eslint
npm WARN   dev eslint@"^5.16.0" from cross-spawn@7.0.3
npm WARN   node_modules/.pnpm/cross-spawn@7.0.3/node_modules/cross-spawn
npm WARN     cross-spawn@7.0.3
npm WARN     node_modules/.pnpm/hexo-util@2.7.0/node_modules/cross-spawn
npm WARN     cross-spawn@7.0.3
npm WARN     node_modules/.pnpm/node_modules/cross-spawn
npm WARN   4 more (eslint-config-moxy, eslint-plugin-babel, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer eslint@">= 6.0.0" from babel-eslint@11.0.0-beta.2
npm WARN node_modules/.pnpm/cross-spawn@7.0.3/node_modules/babel-eslint
npm WARN   babel-eslint@"^11.0.0-beta.0" from eslint-config-moxy@7.1.0
npm WARN   node_modules/.pnpm/cross-spawn@7.0.3/node_modules/eslint-config-moxy
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/zhangyun/.npm/_logs/2022-12-02T01_51_51_393Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried running `npm cache clear --force`, or changing the npm mirror, but that didn't work

Comment: try deleting the node module folder and running the command again,  eslint@">= 6.0.0" this tho is the package that gives the problem

Comment: upstream issue: [\[BUG\] npm link <package>: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'matches')](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4367)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This issue can be potentially resolved through two approaches for **two kinds of people**:

##### For people suffering network restrictions

Same here (Blocked by GFW by our gov).
Just use [cnpm](https://github.com/cnpm/cnpm). I got same errors even though I have a proxy or set mirror to `taobao.com`.

```
// use mirror to install
npm install -g cnpm --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org
```

Then install using `cnpm install` which works for me.

##### For people with free access to real Network

The [Highest score](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76425114/17001641) answered by gilly3 might be viable.

Answer (score 71):

This error shows up when you run `npm install` in a directory where you previously ran `pnpm install`.  The solution is to remove your `node_modules` directory and run `npm install` again.

Comment: Also happens if you run `npm uninstall` in the same directory where you previously ran `pnpm install`

Answer (score 8):

If you are using pnpm, stick to that and do not use npm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

After trying all these solutions, had the idea to use a different network adapter (android phone tether, as i was on wifi). The phone is connected to exactly the same wifi network, but now pnpm and npm came back to life again just like that. So for me it was somehow a network adapter related issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I was actually using `pnpm` as my package manager but had erroneously typed `npm i`.

So the solution is to just run `pnpm i` instead.

Not the clearest of error messages..